# How can I see my ping in Overwatch?

Tags: overwatch

As with most online games, I like to see numbers behind lag I'm experiencing. I know the game shows notifications about [extrapolation and packet loss](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/264971/what-do-these-two-symbols-thunderbolt-stack-of-pages-mean) by default, but not ping. How can I see my ping?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Enable the option "Display performance stats" in the video options.

This will show FPS and ping, in the top left corner.

[image: Screenshot sowing statistics]

Comment: Ping is the one shown as "PNG" on the top left corner btw.

Comment: is TMP the graphics card temperature, or CPU?

Comment: @user1306322 I have no idea, I'll see if I can get some other software reading the sensors running alongside next time I play.

Comment: @user1306322 It is your GPU temp. I tested it against HWMonitor and MSI Afterburner just to be sure.

Comment: On PC, the default keybind to toggle this is `Ctrl + Shift + R`.

Answer (score 9):

Expanding on [Kevin van der Velden's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/266801/181240), the "**Video**" options were changed in an update to allow showing or hiding individual performance stats.

After enabling "**Display Performance Stats**", open the "**Advanced Performance Stats**" section below and make sure that "**Show Network Latency**" is enabled.

In addition to displaying ping, the section also has options for "**Framerate**", "**GPU Temperature**", "**VRAM Usage**", and "**Network Interpolation Delay**"

[image: Advanced performance stats]

Answer (score 1):

**Control + Shift + R** is the default setting to toggle it. If you scroll down to the bottom of controls you can find an option to change it.